# Map JS error line number to unminified unbundled asset file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, runtime-error, bundling-and-minification, r.js

I bundle all my JS assets into one minified uglified file via r.js (part of requirejs).

If any unhandled errors occur on the browser, I use raygun (like Airbrake) to report it back to me. The only problem is the line number I get in my error message, refers to the bundled minified file. Which doesn't help much.

Is there a way to correctly map the line number of my single minified and uglified bundled asset, into the individual JS file with the correct line number?

Comment: You're looking for a source map: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#sourcemaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is have `r.js` generate a source map of the bundle. To do this, in the options you pass to `r.js` you need to have the option `generateSourceMaps` set to true and you must set the `optimize` option to `"uglify2"` or

> "closure" with a closure compiler jar build after r1592 (20111114 release)."

(I'm citing from [this documentation](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js).) I've done it with optimize set to `"uglify2"` and was able to get decent references to the original source code in Chrome.

The logging service must also support it. This [post](http://raygun.io/thinktank/suggestion/1282) over at the raygun forums suggests that raygun does not yet support source maps.

Someone created a [list of such services](https://gist.github.com/cheeaun/5835757) as a gist over at github. Some of the services are marked as supporting source maps. I can't vouch for its accuracy but it could be a good starting point to find a service that supports it.

Comment: Thanks for the list - it was helpful to pick another service until raygun supports sourcemaps ...